# React Native: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know this can happen when a component repeatedly calls `setState` inside `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate` but in my situation even if I call `setState` just one time after that I got this error. Here is my `state` and `componentDidUpdate`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { usernameAlreadyUsing: false };
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.props.usernames.includes(this.props.username)) {
        this.setState({ usernameAlreadyUsing: true });
    }
}
```

Comment: how your component is called?i mean how render method of parent component call your component?

Comment: I understood what you are trying to tell me, I ensure you my parent component call my component just one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time `setState` called `componentDidUpdate` recalls itself. So
this situation causes you to enter an endless loop.

Here try this,

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { usernameAlreadyUsing: false };
}
componentDidUpdate() {
     const { usernameAlreadyUsing } = this.state;
    if(this.props.usernames.includes(this.props.username) && !usernameAlreadyUsing) {
        this.setState({ usernameAlreadyUsing: true });
    }
}
```

With this implementation your code only enters one time in `componentDidUpdate`.

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, shame on me :D

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { usernameAlreadyUsing: false };
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
if(this.props.usernames.length != prevProps.usernames.length) {
         if(this.props.usernames.includes(this.props.username)) {
        this.setState({ usernameAlreadyUsing: true });
    }
    }
  
}
```

try. this, problem with your above is , once its setting username is already present, its again calling setState as the condition succeeds every time. try this

Hope it helps.feel free for doubts